# Symfony 4 How To Use a Bundle To Share Entities + Repo Across Apps

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've a need to link 2 applications to the same database and same entities in Symfony 4, after some reading around it looks like this can be done with bundles. I've not actually worked with bundles before as i cam into symfony at version 4 where it wasn't really needed.

I've not been able to find any documentation for it, i see symfony's here https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html but this just explains how to create the structure, it doesn't explain how to then use the bundle across the two apps.

Please could someone point out where i would find this information, or perhaps an example? My current setup is as follows:

api -> main app with symfony 4
admin -> my second app which will run an admin interface but is separate from the main app, this is the one that needs to share entities with api app.

I have so far created the directories in the "admin" one like:

src/MyOrg/MyOrgBundle/MyOrdBundle.php

I have then loaded this in the config/bundles.php -> this is where i am now a bit lost. The main thing is, i can't figure out how to load my bundle into both applications from a shared location, i don't really want to duplicate the files in both apps if i can get away with it.

**UPDATE**
I have just been playing around with config/doctrine.yaml and changed the following to test:

```
mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                #dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/../share/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

When i run php bin/console make:entity and put TestShare for example, it produces this error:

> [ERROR] Only annotation or attribute mapping is supported by
> make:entity, but the App\Entity\TestingShare
> class uses a different format. If you would like this command to generate the properties & getter/setter methods,
> add your mapping configuration, and then re-run this command with the --regenerate flag.

And it creates the entity in src/Entity instead of ../share/Entity - but i just told it where to put them in the config?

Comment: Bundle code is shared using the composer packaging system.  Same as any other software package.  So this is mostly a composer question.  You can look at the vendor/symfony/make-bundle code for a faily simple example of creating a composer.json file for a package.  Plenty of generic packages examples out there as well.

Comment: By the way, if you just want to share entities then a bundle is not needed.  You can just use a package and configure with: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-entities-outside-of-a-bundle.  And don't attempt to use make:entity to create entities outside of the App namespace.  Was not designed for it.  This sort of broad question is not a real good fit for stackoverflow.  Might want to try on the [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/) board.

Comment: Thank you I’ll look at that documentation , that also explains why the make entity didn’t work. So I have to manually create them

Comment: @Cerad i literally created the shared entity and repo classes and try to schema update php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force and i just get this "No Metadata Classes to process" - i tried to clear and warm up the cache but nope

Comment: There are simply too many possible problems for me to provide a solution.  It is one of the reasons I suggested moving to Reddit.  In any event, consider creating a fresh Symfony application and then creating an entirely independent directory for your shared code with one simple entity.  Then you can focus on how to wire the two together without getting distracted by existing code.  At the very least you can check in the two repos and maybe someone will take a look.

Comment: Ok mate thanks for your input.